# Detrended Cross Correlation in R

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, stationarity

I am looking at determining the relationship between two non-stationary time series, i.e. monthly `cost` and `sales` for a period of 3 years. Is there any R library to come up with a correlogram for between the two non-stationary data series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the variables to make them stationary and then run the regular cross-correlation analysis. Your series may be (1) trend-stationary or (2) difference stationary. If (1), you may detrend your data; if (2), you may difference your data. (Of course, there are other forms of nonstationarity such as conditional or unconditional heteroskedasticity, structural breaks and other, but I leave these out for simplicity.)

For a more complete analysis, you may consider the following. If (1), you could model your series as a vector autoregression (VAR) with a trend. If (2), you could conduct cointegration analysis. If you find presence of cointegration, you could build a vector error correction model (VECM). If you find no cointegration, you could build a VAR model for the first differences of your data.

Whether (1) or (2), impulse-response analysis and forecast error variance decomposition (FEVD) should give you information on how the variables interact. This will provide a more complete picture than just the analysis of cross correlations.

Since your sample is quite short, the model you will ultimately use should be as parsimonious as possible; otherwise you may suffer from overfitting.

Also, do not forget to account for seasonality if there is any. This can be done either by seasonally adjusting the data before further analysis or incorporating seasonal features in your models, e.g. monthly dummy variables in your VAR or VECM models.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Actually, I am trying to determine how monthly Fixed cost and Variable cost are behaving against monthly Sales and thereafter building models to forecast Fixed and Variable costs with Sales (identifying monthly leads and lags) as predictor. I am trying to implement the steps you have explained above. Feel free if you would like to add something.